# Accelerometer beacon as game controller lag

Tags: sensor

As part of our product, we use a sensor/beacon to measure the inclination/angle of the product. We do this with a KKM 3-axis accelerometer (model: https://www.kkmcn.com/long-range-beacon-k5p). However, we face a big problem in the inaccuracy or lag of the sensor that controls the game on the mobile phone. The sensor is used in iBeacon mode with an advertising interval of 20ms (but the actual measurement shows a much higher interval). We ran into a wall where we don't know exactly which direction to explore. The sensors are set using the manufacturer's application, and the firmware has already been adjusted so that it is even possible to set the advertising interval to 20ms (default is the lowest 100ms). Could the problem be that we use the iBeacon protocol and not a direct connection to the sensor?

[image: app settings]